# How can I solve java.util.HashMap error?

Tags: java

I have took below failures in my trace when trying to run the application. I do not undertand the reason behind this error. Is it result from `static` keyword, or is one thread trying to modify something in this code segment? Importantly, how can I solve this error?

Failure Trace

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
```

The Code segment

```
// Type of holder is --> HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>>

Set<Integer> keys = holder.keySet();
HashMap<String, Integer> temp = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 

for(int iter : keys){
    temp = holder.get(iter); 
    if(temp == null || temp.size() == 0){
          holder.remove(iter);
    }
}
```

Should I use lock around some statement or all of them? Not knowing the real problem restrict to find a solution. Anyway, thanks

Comment: Use `java.util.Iterator`, in fact not post as `HashMap error`. Why not google firstly with `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` as your error said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can call `holder.remove()` while you are iterating the `holder` keys. Instead, you can do it with one something like

```
HashMap<String, Integer> temp = null; // <-- why create one?
List<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();

for(int iter : keys) {
    temp = holder.get(iter); 
    if (temp == null || temp.size() == 0) {
          toRemove.add(iter);
    }
}
keys.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Or, per the [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) Javadocs -

> if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` method, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: If I understand [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) correctly, he might also be able to do `keys.iterator()` to obtain an Iterator for the keySet, iterate it and directly call `.remove()` when necessary to remove a value from it *and its backing map* (= `holder`).

Answer (score -1):

You can't change the contents of an `Iterable` while iterating over it. Instead you could store the relevant values in a list and then remove them after the loop has finished.

the call to `holder.remove()` causes the `HashMap` to change its contents which in turn changes its keyset that you are using for the loop, thus causing the exception.